# how to make a list of images and draw them in random position in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame, move

I need to draw sprites in random position in the screen, how can I do this?

```
class SpriteOrange(MyGame):
def __init__(self, image):
    self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
def draw1(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.image, self.x, self.y)

def update(self):
    self.x = random.randrange(0, 400)
    self.y = random.randrange(0, 400)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create class `SpriteOrange` with function `draw(screen)` and `update()` (to randomly change position):

```
class SpriteOrange():

    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(0,400)
        self.y = random.randrange(0,400)
```

You can create list of instances of SpriteOrange

```
self.oranges = []

for x in range(10):
    self.oranges.append(SpriteOrange('orange.png'))
```

You can change positions:

```
for o in self.oranges:
    o.update()
```

You can draw:

```
for o in self.oranges:
    o.draw(self.screen)
```

If you need more read about [pygame.sprite.Sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and [pygame.sprite.Group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)

Comment: you ranges cannot work, you are calling update on an integer returned by range. A `for o in self.oranges` is what you want.

Comment: one more thing, since all of the orange sprites are the same picture, there is no need to load a new image for each orange. I suggest putting a image as a parameter, as opposed to sending an image path.

Comment: I assumed that OP would want to use SpriteOrange with different images and use it as example to create SpriteWitch.

Comment: well he already had a list of 3 oranges that all pointed to the same surface in memory. But you are right, we should not worry about memory in such a small program.

Comment: I've done everything as you said and I edited my code how it looks now, but now I have another problem, python says me:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mygame.py", line 122, in <module>
    MyGame().run()
AttributeError: 'MyGame' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski it doesn't really matter, but I am not "he" :P

Comment: @user2926550 fix your indentation, move your SpriteOrange class to the top, and fix your MyGame methods to be on the same indentation level as `def __init__(self)`

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski if I put it on the top I have: class SpriteOrange(MyGame):
NameError: name 'MyGame' is not defined pastebin is probably better to past the code http://pastebin.com/sVXfg58R

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski wait,I've done with it, now new problem:   File "mygame.py", line 20, in draw1
    screen.blit(self.image, self.x, self.y)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

Comment: @user2926550 `class SpriteOrange():` not `class SpriteOrange(MyGame):`, in SpriteOrange `def draw(self):` not `def draw1(self):`, (my mistake) `screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))` not `screen.blit(self.image, self.x, self.y)` - and now I can run it :)

Comment: @user2926550 to center text you can use `rect = self.fontim.get_rect(center=self.screen.get_rect().center)`. I use special property `center` in [pygame.Rect()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

Comment: @user2926550 in `draw()` you add `SpriteOrange` to list so every frame you have more sprites on screen - is this what you intended ?

Comment: @furas no, I need them to blit only once in random position, my first original code blited  every frame new sprites, but yeah, I've done with it )